# unityで　Parameter 'MoveSpeed' does not exist. というエラーが出ます！

Tags: unity3d

日本語訳すると「パラメーター "MoveSpeed" は存在しません。」ということだと思いますが、似たようなエラーでよくあるスクリプトのタイプミスなどは確認しました。
移動スピードをanimatorに反映させるためのスクリプトです。何卒よろしくお願いします。

**エラー本文**

```
Parameter 'MoveSpeed' does not exist.
UnityEngine.Animator:SetFloat (string,single)
PlayerController:Update () (at Assets/iigeemu/script/PlayerController.cs:51)
```

**ソースコード**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Animator animator;
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 10;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpPower = 3;
    private CharacterController _characterController;

    private Transform _transform;
    private Vector3 _moveVelocity;
    private Transform _transform;
    private Vector3 _moveVelocity;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        _transform = transform;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        {
            Debug.Log(_characterController.isGrounded ? "地上にいます" : "空中です");


            _moveVelocity.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
            _moveVelocity.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed;

            _transform.LookAt(_transform.position + new Vector3(_moveVelocity.x, 0, _moveVelocity.z));
            if (_characterController.isGrounded)
            {
                if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
                {

                    Debug.Log("ジャンプ!");
                    _moveVelocity.y = jumpPower;
                }
            }
            else
            {

                _moveVelocity.y += Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;
            }

            _characterController.Move(_moveVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        
        animator.SetFloat("MoveSpeed", new Vector3(_moveVelocity.x, 0,_moveVelocity.z).magnitude);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Animaor.SetFloat() メソッドは Animator コンポーネントを通じて（Animator コンポーネントにアサインされている）Animator Controller アセットにパラメーターを渡すメソッドです。

該当のエラーによってわかることは、現在対象となっている Animator Controller に該当のパラメーターが存在していない、ということです。

あとは、パラメーター名を間違えたならそれを直すなり、Animator Controller のパラメーターを追加するなり適宜修正すればよいです。

#### 参照

- [Unity ユーザーマニュアル - アニメーションパラメーター](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2020.3/Manual/AnimationParameters.html)

Answer (score 0):

animator.SetFloat("MoveSpeed" のSpeed→speedに小文字変換したらどうでしょうか？